# Why will this jQuery only work once?

Tags: jquery

I have a container that is supposed to change its style and display different messages depending on what event triggers.
Message displaying part will ALWAYS work, while style will change only ONCE for some weird reason, at other attempts to change style, it will just stay the same.

this is the first and the only one that works entirely

```
$('#feedback_message_signup_final').css({"visibility": "visible", "color": "#347C17", "left": "27.5%"});
$('#feedback_message_signup_final').html('В данный момент вы инициализировали регистрацию на проекте \'Фаворит\'.<br> В настоящее время сервис распространяется лишь на три города: Актобе, Алматы и Астану.<br> Мы обязательно будем работать над расширением зоны действия нашего проекта.<br> Надеемся, что процесс регистрации будет для вас легким и интерактивным.');
```

one of the subsequent ones. all of them display the message, but 
 will not break the string accordingly, nor will the css be changed in accordance with the function..

```
if (data=='false'){
                $('#feedback_message_signup_final').css({"visibility": "visible", "color": "#CC0000"});
        $('#feedback_message_signup_final').html('Ошибка при связи с СУБД. Форма заполнена корректно, ошибок нет.<br> Пожалуйста, попробуйте нажать на кнопку \'Регистрация\' еще раз для повторной связи с СУБД.');
                }
            var response_from_signuphandler = JSON.stringify(data);
            $('#feedback_message_signup_final').css({"visibility": "visible", "color": "#347C17"});
        $('#feedback_message_signup_final').html('Поздравляем! Вы успешно зарегистрированы на проекте \'Фаворит\'.<br> Для того, чтобы начать пользоваться сайтом, вам нужно будет подтвердить регистрацию,<br> введя авторизационный код, который мы вам уже выслали по E-mail.<br> При первом входе на сайт, вы увидите запрос авторизационного кода, вам нужно будет ввести код,<br> просто скопировав его из полученного E-mail\'а и введя в указанном поле.');
        },
        error: function(){
        $('#feedback_message_signup_final').css({"visibility": "visible", "color": "#CC0000", "left":"25.8%"});
    $('#feedback_message_signup_final').html('Ошибка при обработке запроса сервером. Форма заполнена корректно, ошибок нет.<br> Пожалуйста, попробуйте нажать на кнопку \'Регистрация\' еще раз для повторного серверного запроса.');
        }
```

Comment: JavaScript has booleans, `=="false"` is considered bad style. Also, not reusing selectors is considered bad style. Consider using more variables and less selectors and looking up booleans in JavaScript.

Comment: What does `data` actually equal?

Comment: could that "false" somehow affect that only a portion of what had been intended was executed correctly?

Comment: whatever `data` is, it will not affect your code unless its changed. from my experience, pretty words like 'data' are usually already taken by your browser or one of its plugins, change your `data` variable to something like `myData` and see if the problem persists

Comment: also note, that if you attach custom event handlers to your elements, the event handlers will be removed if the elements are reloaded. consider event delegation or make sure to reattach your handlers if elements are reloaded.

Comment: how would you explain the other part of code working under the same if condition?